# Accessing data attributes in a dynically created table using JQuery v1.7.2

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass values to a modal.  I'm having to use jquery version 1.7.2.  I can't do this because the problem I'm having is that the html doesn't appear to be in the dom when I try to access it.

I have a table of data and I want to access data attributes within the table rows.  The problem is that my table rows are appended to the DOM using the append() function and seemingly when I try to click on a table element and access the relevant row I get an undefined error in the console.

I have all my javascript within a document.ready function but it doesn't seem to be having the desired effect.

If I hard code a table row with the data attributes I want to access it works fine.

```
$j(document).ready(function () {  
$j('#myModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show:false,

}).on('show', function(){
      var getGenotypeFromRow = $j(this).data('modalgenotype');
      console.log('getGenotypeFromRow')
      console.log(getGenotypeFromRow)
    //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
    $j(this).find('.modal-body').html($j('<b> Genotype selected: ' + getGenotypeFromRow  + '</b>'))
});

$j("#search-results-table").find('tr[data-target]').on('click', function(){
    //or do your operations here instead of on show of modal to populate values to modal.
     $j('#myModal').data('modalgenotype',$j(this).data('genotype'));
});



var search_id_1 = $searchTool.doSearch({
                "gene_id": "673",
            }, function(data, resultset_length, current_index, more_data) {

                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    $('#search-results-table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr class="row" data-toggle="modal" data-genotype="'+data[i].Genotype+'"><td>'+data[i].Genotype+'</td><td>'+data[i].Short_Desc+'</td><td>'+data[i].Gene_ID+'</td><td>'+data[i].Parental_Cell_Line+'</td><td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-genotype="'+data[i].Genotype+'">Launch demo modal</a></td><td><a href="#" class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</a></td></tr>');
                }


                current_chunk++;
                if(current_chunk >= max_chunks) {
                    $highland_search.cancelSearch(search_id_1);
                }
            });
});
```

Hard coded table (this works):

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-genotype="12345xyz" data-target="#myModal">
    <td>12345xyz</td>
        <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can load my table rows dynamically and access data attributes on the table rows?

Comment: I always use .attr() instead of .data() because of the fact that dynamically created content's data-attributes can't be accessed with .data() but you can with .attr(). Can you give that a try?

Comment: I can't seem to get any luck with that unfortunately.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a live copy or any script we can view? Would help a lot ;)

Comment: I've eventually solved this.  I solved it another way though.  I created a modal for each table row.  Seems to work :)